# Attach projector screen to a ceiling... but the width does not match the studs. Ideas?

Tags: mounting, studs, projector

The roll-out screen has holes at the ends of the metal casing, but these don't match the distance between the studs. The screen is ~80" wide.

Also, I am looking for a portable solution where I can easily detach the rolled-up screen when not in use.

I am thinking of mounting screws with hooks (or eyes) in the studs, and

**option one**:

- possibly using equal-length metal wire to connect the screw holes on the screen to the eyes on the screws (via carabiners or something like that)

**option two**:

- buy a 2x2 and cut to the width of the screen,
- mount the screen to the bottom of the 2x2 and
- add screws with hooks to its top, matching in position the screws in the ceiling studs.

Other ideas? Possible issues with what I have planned?

Answer (score 2):

Most screens have both screw-mounts and hang-mounts (loops) built in - the loops often fold if not in use. If your screen does not have the loops then you could add your stick/board to it to get some. Or it may have largish-holes that a chain screw-joint link could be placed through on the end-caps.

Use the hang-mounts and chains and screw-joint links as seen on trailer safety chains (or carabiners if you'll be moving it frequently, I guess, and it's not a public-ish location.) It's actually more stable if the hooks on the wall are wider than the hooks on the screen, so the chains angle in. Use chain, not wire. I speak from experience on that point - also use chain and links a good deal stronger than the weight of the screen would seem to require.

Comment: Sounds good. How do you get chain cut to the desired length? Will Home Depot do this?

Comment: I generally get it cut "long enough", and leave any extra links hanging (from the wall end where they don't rattle on the screen), unless I feel like being overly neat, in which case I'll take a hacksaw to it. If I remember I'll try to grab a picture of one tomorrow. It preserves the ability to adjust and does not detract from the appearance (IMHO.) If you are sure of the precise length you need I'm sure most places will happily cut it that way, though some may want to sell you an even number of feet, so you may end up with a short piece or two.